# Weighted mean for each row

Tags: r, dplyr, weighted, weighted-average

I have the following dataset, `indexIPI_branques_EU_wide`, and I want to calculate the weighted mean for different columns:

```
structure(list(geo = c("Alemanya", "Espanya"), time = structure(c(19417, 
11961), class = "Date"), C10 = c(115.7, 103), C11 = c(104.9, 
120.6), C12 = c(70.2, NA), C13 = c(98.3, 232), C14 = c(77.3, 
275), C15 = c(127.6, 268.8), C16 = c(105.7, 255.7), C17 = c(91.2, 
106.5), C18 = c(70.7, 151.6), C19 = c(90.3, 84.9), C20 = c(87.9, 
106.5), C21 = c(135.5, 83.2), C22 = c(105.2, 126.8), C23 = c(101.8, 
266.8), C24 = c(96.2, 137.5), C25 = c(113.2, 183.8), C26 = c(145, 
176.7), C27 = c(126, 170.4), C28 = c(108.7, 129.1), C29 = c(104.5, 
128.1), C30 = c(153.8, 177), C31 = c(94.3, 300.9), C32 = c(127.4, 
138.1), C33 = c(111.9, 92.4), D35 = c(89, 96.1), E36 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

For instance, I want to add a new column, `alimentacio` that should be equal to the weighted mean of `C10`, `C11` and `C12`.  Such as alimentació = C10*[C10/(C10+C11+C12)] + C11*[C11/(C10+C11+C12)] + C12*[C12/(C10+C11+C12)]

I've tried the following:

```
branques_Idescat_EU <- indexIPI_branques_EU_wide %>% 
  mutate(alimentació = weighted.mean(indexIPI_branques_EU_wide$C10, indexIPI_branques_EU_wide$C11, indexIPI_branques_EU_wide$C12))
```

But I get the same value for each row, when it should be different for each row (because `geo` and `time` are changing along the dataset).

Comment: Almost "never" use `indexIPI_branques_EU_wide$` in a pipe that is based off of `indexIPI_branques_EU_wide`: at best, it is inefficient, but if there are any verbs that change the data (e.g., `mutate`, `filter`, `arrange`), then either your pipe will break (loudly) or silently corrupt your data. Don't do that.

Comment: Your desired output isn't clear.  Do you want rowwise weighted means? If so, weighted by what?

Comment: I don't know if you're using `weighted.mean` correctly. You are passing it three arguments, and it is using `x=C10` (the values whose weighted mean is to be computed), `w=C11` (a numerical vector of weights), and `...=C12` (arguments passed to other methods). If I understand correctly, you want the weighted mean of C10, C11, and C12 ... but where are the weights?

Answer (score 1):

I'm inferring `dplyr`, though the solution can be adapted easily to base R or `data.table` "dialects" of R.

Try this:

```r
indexIPI_branques_EU_wide %>%
  mutate(alimentacio = rowMeans(pick(C10, C11, C12), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  select(-(C13:E36))
# # A tibble: 2 × 6
#   geo      time         C10   C11   C12 alimentacio
#   <chr>    <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 Alemanya 2023-03-01  116.  105.  70.2        96.9
# 2 Espanya  2002-10-01  103   121.  NA         112.
```

(The use of `select` is purely to reduce the output for this answer.)

There's nothing in the sample data that suggests to me the presence of "weights", so I wonder if the use of `weighted.means` is a misunderstanding of the rowwise operation.

Comment: I wonder if it's worth including an answer using `rowwise() |> mutate(alimentacio = mean(c_across(C10, C11, C12), na.rm = TRUE))` as well.

Comment: `rowwise` has its uses, but its performance is generally not as good (often "poor") as array-friendly functions such as `rowMeans`. But if you feel it's a benefit, feel free to post another answer

Comment: I understand the performance considerations, I just think users are likely to encounter this kind of answer on other questions. I think just this comment is enough.

Comment: Weighted by the value of C10 among (C10+C11+C12), and so on. For instance: alimentació = C10*[C10/(C10+C11+C12)] + C11*[C11/(C10+C11+C12)] + C12*[C12/(C10+C11+C12)]

Comment: Please edit your question, add that context, and please add your expected output for those values. Thanks.